# Shutdown halting on: wating for process brltty

Tags: linux, arch-linux, shutdown

I just installed edeavour OS and whenever I shut down the laptop it keeps getting stuck on `Wating for process brltty`, for a good 30 seconds. Does anyone know what to do to fix it getting stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brltty` is a braille display driver. If you don’t use one you can probably uninstall it or as a first step check if there is a service running that can be disabled

Answer (score 0):

Since `brltty` is apparently used for a braille terminal interface, it has no use for me so just removing it worked.